# Select optgroup matches based on week,day

Tags: php, mysql, fetch

Sorry for bad title, my english is bad.

```
<select class="chosen2" name="mac" onchange="this.form.submit()">
<option></option>
<?php 
error_reporting(0); 
$maclist = mysql_query("SELECT year,split,leagueid,takim,versus,mac,week,day
FROM league WHERE id >= 0 $ligsarry $yearsarrf $splitsarrf GROUP by mac ORDER BY hafta desc,gun desc,mac desc,side asc, id asc");
while ($macs=mysql_fetch_array($maclist)) {
?>
  <option <?php if (isset($_GET['mac']) && $_GET['mac']==$macs['mac']) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> value="<?php echo $macs['mac']; ?>"><?php echo $macs['mac'] . " -- W" . $macs['week'] . "D" . $macs['day'];;?></option>

<?php }?>
</select>
```

Im getting this result with this code:

[image]

I want to add `<optgroup label="Week 1 Day 2"> -w1d2 matches- </optgroup>`
and `<optgroup label="Week 1 Day 1"> -w1d1 matches- </optgroup>`

But i dont know how to do this. Match count in a day is not always 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
$current_day = 0;

while (...) {

    if ($macs['day'] != $current_day) {

        if ($current_day > 0) {
            print '</optgroup>';
        }            

        print '<optgroup>';

        $current_day = $macs['day'];
    }

    print '<option>...</option>';

}

if ($current_day > 0) {
    print '</optgroup>';
}
```

Every time you read a new `$macs['day']` then print an `<optgroup>`

Comment: I've made some changes, please try again!

Comment: It is working but i had to remove last `if ($current_day > 0) {
    print '</optgroup>';
}`  it was closing optgroup tag after first child of optgroup i removed it and its working great thank you!

Comment: mmm... may be you writed that `if` inside the loop, it has to be outside to ensure that the last group is closed